# DataTemplate.DataType alternative in Silverlight

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight

I have a view model with a property `Fields` which is an `ObservableCollection<FieldVM>`. In the view that uses this property, I have an `ItemsControl` like so:

```
...
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}" />
...
```

`FieldVM` is an abstract class, implemented by such classes as `TextFieldVM` and `EnumFieldVM`. During run time, these `FieldVM`-implementations get added to the `Fields` property and I want them to show up in my view with their associated views.

In WPF, doing this is simple, I do it all the time. You just do this in an appropriate resource dictionary, and everything works as expected:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TextFieldVM}">
    <v:TextFieldView />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:EnumFieldVM}">
    <v:EnumFieldView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Now, working in Silverlight for the first time, I expected I could just do the same thing, but the `DataTemplate` doesn't have a `DataType` property. I'm stumped. What's the Silverlight-way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a Value Converter to bind the type to the visibility of each view:

```
<DataTemplate> 
    <Grid>
        <v:EnumFieldView 
            Visibilty="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ViewVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Enum}" /> 
        <v:TextFieldView 
            Visibilty="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ViewVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Text}" />
    </Grid
</DataTemplate>
```

And in the ConvertTo of the ViewVisibilityConverter, switch the visibility based on the type.

Another way to look at it would be to use a different type of value converter to return a different data template from the Application.Resources.

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ItemTemplateFactory}"/>
```

in ItemTemplateFactory.Convert():

```
var fieldVM = value as FieldVM;

switch fieldVM.FieldType:
{
    case "Text":
         return Application.Current.Resources["TextTemplate"] as DataTemplate;

    case "Enum":
         return Application.Current.Resources["EnumTemplate"] as DataTemplate;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works, and I'm marking it as the answer, but it's not really an ideal solution... it's more of an ugly hack. I can't help but feel like there has to be a more proper, WPF-like way of doing this.

Comment: I added an additional option that might be a bit prettier:

Comment: @Alex: I realize I'm a year late to the game here, but I implemented a `BooleanVisibility` attached behavior which you might find interesting. You can find the write-up here: http://www.executableintent.com/attached-behaviors-part-1-booleanvisibility/. Part 2 of the series has a code sample with an attached behavior framework and the `BooleanVisibility` implementation.

Comment: There seem to be two solutions mentioned here. The first is not good, as it uses Visibility rather than proper templating. You will find that the resources and memory for *all* the templates is loaded, so it is inefficient. Your second solution seems fine.

Answer (score 8):

[Microsoft Prism library](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) has custom DataTemplateSelector implementation, notice Classnames in DataTemplate x:keys:

```
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <prism:DataTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False">
                            <prism:DataTemplateSelector.Resources>
                                <DataTemplate x:Key="OpenQuestionViewModel">
                                    <Views:OpenQuestionView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>

                                <DataTemplate x:Key="MultipleSelectionQuestionViewModel">
                                    <Views:MultipleSelectionView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>

                                <DataTemplate x:Key="NumericQuestionViewModel">
                                    <Views:NumericQuestionView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </prism:DataTemplateSelector.Resources>
                        </prism:DataTemplateSelector>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 5):

Silverlight 5 will finally include this functionality. Until then the marked answer is one of the better ways I've seen.

Comment: ...and since Silverlight 5 has now shipped, you no longer need this sort of workaround. You have to leave out the {x:Type } bit, and just specify the type name though.

Answer (score 4):

A variant on the second option from Michael (since I could not get it working directly).

In resources define an additional datatemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DynamicTemplate">
  <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TemplateChooser}}" Content="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And then use this data template in the listbox

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DynamicTemplate}">
```

TemplateChooser must be an IValueConvertor, where the Convert function takes an object and returns the DataTemplate that should be used for that object.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but a nice tip for an items control.

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight doesn't have a DataTemplateSelector but I used this snippet...

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <client:TemplateSelector Content="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Here's the template selector:

```
public class TemplateSelector : ContentControl
{
    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);

        MyObject f = newContent as MyObject;

        switch (f.MyProperty)
        {
            case "Bool":
            case "String":
            case "Array":
            default:
                ContentTemplate = Application.Current.Resources["MultiSelectDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DataTemplateSelector is not available in Silverlight either...
But I've seen a few tries to implement this class in Silverlight.
Here's one:
http://skysigal.xact-solutions.com/Blog/tabid/427/EntryId/1000/Silverlight-a-port-of-the-DataTemplateSelector.aspx

Comment: DataTemplateSelector is not part of Silverlight 4

Comment: You're right.  I used another snippet as a replacement.  Editing.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/1937/ presents what looks like a nice do-it-yourself data template selector masquerading as a value converter. It has the advantage that there is no need to install Prism.

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried to neglect the DataType property?
and just write something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <v:TextFieldView />
</DataTemplate>
```

worked for me

Comment: The purpose of the `DataType` property is to allow for dynamic selection of templates - the template that applies to the appropriate data type is used, and the others ignored. In your answer the TetxFieldView will be used every time.