# How to set default datatype

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have an ItemsControl in which all the items except the type `AType` should have the same view. How could I do that?

I've tried `object` as `DataType` but it is forbidden (there is simplified example below):

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="AType">                                                
            <TextBox />                                             
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="System:Object">
            <Border>     
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />                                           
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>                                    
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: In Silverlight, DataTemplate doesn't have a DataType property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400522/datatemplate-datatype-alternative-in-silverlight

Comment: Memoizer, It has in 5 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best bet is to use a Template Selector, [like this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92439/Silverlight-DataTemplateSelector)

That way you can easily specify the template based on whatever condition you like.